# Installing windows from Linux mint

Tags: windows

I have an iso of windows xp and I am currently running Linux mint 8 Helena (we don't gave a proper connection to download the latest) . Since my DVD drive isn't working I need to make a boot able USB pen drive to install windows. Please suggest a method not involving too much textual commands . it has 'wine' but common windows utilities do not work. Maybe irrelevant but the processor is core 2duo t6400 3gb ram Intel GMA 4500 MHD..

Comment: This is fundamentally an opinion-based question. That's why I downvoted it. My own suggestion, for instance, would ***not*** involve any version of Windows at all.

Comment: But from linux mint i need to install it. Windows forum guys will be less knowledgeable than people here who obviously knows more about mint.

Comment: Agreed. And i would happily alter my vote if my comment were not true. Maybe you could alter your question in some way to disprove it?

Comment: Pardon. You meant to say I should not post any windows related questions here?

Comment: Not whatsoever. I meant you should not ask me to **'suggest**  a  **good** software.' Asking how you might accomplish your goal would be more to the point, i think.

Comment: you should try virtual box maybe

Comment: Thank you.but I would like to install it directly on the hard drive. I have the iso. I wonder why isn't there an easily found tool to transfer it to a usb while being boot able..

Comment: You can install directly to the harddrive with virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Slow connection so will take a while to download virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). You need a USB pen drive for it

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Can you please provide a link? Maybe that version will work.

Comment: What procedure you followed ? What is the error ?

Comment: I installed both unetbootins for windows and linux. The windows one runs in wine but couldn't render the window properly. The linux version asks for administrative password and gets very content with it and gives no more feedback.    Its going a bit out of linux here but is it going to work if i copy the iso in a windows 8 laptop and use unetbootin from there? I guess it does not support windows iso s. The official microsoft tool does Not work with XP and supports newer versions only.

Comment: try this http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Comment: Thank you . My version is maybe too old to support unetbootin and it is not running. I guess I have to do it in some other windows pc. Vote Up is not working for me or i would. :)